# Custom Point Shader in Autodesk Forge Viewer behaves weirdly with orthograpic Camera

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using a PointCloud for fast rendering of sprites after [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card). Everything works fine with the perspective camera. However, if I switch to the orthographic camera via `viewer.navigation.toOrthographic()` the points' sizes are not calculated correctly. Does anyone know what the issue is or where I might find some clue?

#### My vertex shader

```c
#if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
varying highp vec3 vWorldPosition;
#endif
attribute float mVisible;
attribute float mSize;
varying float vMVisible;
uniform float scale;
void main() {
    vMVisible = mVisible;
    
    #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
    vec4 _worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    vWorldPosition = _worldPosition.xyz;
    #endif

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    gl_PointSize = mSize * (scale / (-mvPosition.z) );
}
```

#### Zoomed out

[image: Normal sized points]

#### Zoomed in

[image: Very large points]

#### Zoomed in a little bit more

[image: No Points shown anymore]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last few lines of the fragment shader:

```cpp
vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
gl_PointSize = mSize * (scale / (-mvPosition.z) );
```

When using an [orthographic projection instead of a perspective projection](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), the `mvPosition` (position transformed into the "normalized device coordinates") may have very different values, and so dividing the point size by `mvPosition.z` may yield unexpected results.

You may need to [clamp](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/clamp.xhtml) the final point size by some constants (or by uniforms you provide from your JavaScript code), e.g.:

```cpp
gl_PointSize = clamp(mSize * scale / -mvPosition.z, 10.0, 100.0);
```